# GNU R, creating a new array

Tags: arrays, r

In GNU R, I wish to create an array of strings from an array of numbers in which I categorise number intervals. For example:

```
x <- c(1:6)
```

The new array shall categorise number intervals as for example:

```
x <= 2 --> "Category A"
x > 2 & x <= 5 --> "Category B"
x > 5 -- > "Category C"
```

So that the new array takes the form of:

```
x1
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cut`

```
 x1 <- as.character(cut(x, breaks=c(0, 2, 5, Inf), labels=LETTERS[1:3]))
 x1
 #[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sapply` function if you need to do something else within the conditions:

```
sapply(x, function(x){
  if(x <= 2){
    "A"
  } else  if (x > 2 && x <= 5){
    "B"
  } else if (x > 5){
    "C"
  }  
})

[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C"
```